# Create new variable using partial string of another variable in SAS

Tags: sas, substr

I am new to SAS and would like to keep what's before the hyphen '-' to create a new variable:

```
 x 
abc-something
efgh-everything
hij-something
```

I tried:

```
DATA NEW 
    set OLD;
    y = (compress(substr([x], 3, 1));
RUN;
PROC PRINT DATA = NEW; 
RUN;
```

to get it to look like this but it doesn't work:

```
 x 
abc
efgh
hij
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the `scan()` function to split a string based on delimiter character(s).

```
y=scan(x,1,'-');
```

Of if you just want to first three characters then use SUBSTR() function.

```
y=substr(x,1,3);
```

Answer (score 1):

Try without square brackets. Compress not required either.

Comment: Hi! Sorry I updated my example. So the method I use doesn't capture everything in front of the hyphen if the length isn't the same. I'm trying to find a solution that grabs everything before the hyphen.